# Java : Return a String in the java.util.Date Format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I will be reciving the Input in this format 201201 , which is YYYYMM format .

Now i want to return the value 201201 as it is , but it it should be in a  java.util.Date format

I am confused

```
String strDate = "201201";  
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMM");
```

**Now i am not able to return in the java.util.Date format with the value as 201201**

I ahve edited the question it must be in YYYYMM format .

I tried this way

```
public class StringToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymm");

        try {
            Date today = df.parse("201201");
            System.out.println(df.format(today));


            //System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear....

Comment: 201201 is in ddMMyyyy format? There are some missing numbers, right? It looks like yyyyMM format.

Comment: I have edited the question it must be in YYYYMM format

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you want.

Comment: The issue is that the return type is in Sun Jan 01 00:01:00 IST 2012
format but i want as 201201 Date Object

Comment: I think you are confused about the difference between a Date object and a String. First, your main method does not return a Date, nor a String. Its return type is void. You are just using System.out to print out a String - which is the only thing you can print. Please explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  mm is minute MM is month

Try :  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");

Then use the parse method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see off is your SimpleDateFormat declaration.  It should be

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");`

Then, `System.out.println(df.format(today));` will return today as "201201"

You'll need to use SimpleDateFormat to get any java.util.date into the desired format you want.

A java.util.date without formatting outputs like "Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2012" as a String.

A java.util.date object can't be set natively with a format of "yyyyMM".

Comment: But the problem is that the (df.format(today) if of type String and i want in Date format

Comment: As I said in my post, you can't set a java.util.Date object to a format of "yyyyMM".  A java.util.Date will always natively be of a format of "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy".  You have to use SimpleDateFormat to get it into any other format and it will return as a String.  No other way around it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymm");` should be `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");`

- `MM` = Month in year
- `mm` = Minute in hour

Comment: Has been answered a week before.